# MS WORD - line joining bullets

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-2007, office-2010

I am working in MS WORD and I need some help with bullets.

I am trying to make a line, joining one bullet with the other in a Word document.

Can anyone please tell me how do I draw a line vertically joining two bullets.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the line  >right click,select format shape>Line Style>Arrow settings>Begin type and end Type